# Python: fastest way to map continuous coordinates to discrete grid?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, coordinates, coordinate-systems

What's the fastest way to discretize continuous `(x, y)` or `(x, y, z)` coordinate data onto their nearest grid coordinates?

Said differently: what's the fastest way to turn the continuous, Euclidean position `(6.778, 9.201)` into a corresponding grid coordinate `(7, 9)` -- for example, the pixel coordinate in an image? Let's imagine I have 100 continuous `(x, y)` pairs and a known 150 x 150 discrete grid (e.g. 150^2 pairs of `(0, 0), (1, 1), ...`, etc. -- what's the fastest way to map each `(x, y)` pair to their nearest `(grid1, grid2)` coordinate?

Googling this didn't seem to give much results, but I'm sure this has been asked elsewhere, so apologies in advance if this is redundant.

Comment: If the grid is evenly spaced, something like `np.round(coordinates/grid_size)` would work.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Are the x-y pairs sorted for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to describe the grid in terms of its spacing and offset:

```
grid_offset = np.array([0.1, 0.3])
grid_spacing = np.array([1., 1.5])
```

In this notation, we take grid points to lie at

```
grid_offset + n * grid_spacing
```

For a given `(x, y)` pair, you can now trivially compute the nearest grid *index* with

```
point = np.array([x, y])
index = np.round((point - grid_offset) / grid_spacing)
```

To convert back into grid coordinates:

```
grid_offset + index * grid_spacing
```

If you have a large number of pairs, make the array shape `(N, 2)` (or 3, or however many dimensions you want). That way, you can broadcast directly with the `(2,)` grid arrays:

```
points = np.array([[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ..., [xn, yn]])
gpoints = grid_offset + np.round((points - grid_offset) / grid_spacing) * grid_spacing
```

However, your greatest speed boost would probably come from transposing the arrays (or defining them in Fortran order). Broadcasted operations on a `(2, N)` and `(2, 1)` array are going to do much fewer cache loads because of the contiguity of the dimensions being worked on.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - the offset part I hadn't even considered, but that makes the solution more general.